# Errors in java program

Tags: java

I am trying to write this java program to add , delete items in array-list. This is what I have coded:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class abc
{
    ArrayList<Int> nums = new ArrayList<Int>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int opt = 0; 

    public void addItem(int i) // add item to list
    {
        nums.add(i);
    }

    public void addItem(int i, int pos) // add item to specific position in list 
    {
        nums.add(pos,i);
    }

    public void delItem(int pos) // delete item at specific position in list 
    {
        nums.remove(pos);
    }   

    public void delItem() // clear all items in list 
    {
        nums.clear();
    }       

    public void showItems()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length ; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("nums[" + i + "] : " + nums[i]);
        }
    }

    public void menu()
    {
        System.out.println("==MENU==");
        System.out.println("1) Add an item");
        System.out.println("2) Add an item to specific position");
        System.out.println("3) Delete an item at specific position");
        System.out.println("4) Clear all items in list");
        System.out.println("5) Exit \n\n");
        System.out.println("Choose an option");
        opt = in.nextInt();
        execute();
    }

    public void execute()
    {
        if(opt == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a value: ");
            int a = in.nextInt();
            addItem(a);
            System.out.println("Item added");
        }
        else if(opt == 2)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a value: ");
            int a = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter a position: ");
            int b = in.nextInt();
            addItem(a,b);
            System.out.println("Item added");
        }
        else if(opt == 3)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a position: ");
            int a = in.nextInt();
            delItem(a);
            System.out.println("Item deleted");
        }
        else if(opt == 4)
        {
            delItem();
            System.out.println("All Items deleted");
        }
    }
}


class pList
{
    public void static main(String args[])
    {
        abc a = new abc();
        while(true)
        {
            a.menu();
            if(a.opt == 5)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if(a.opt > 5)
            {
                a.menu();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I am receiving:

```
C:\Users\Dummy\Desktop\Java>javac pList.java
pList.java:87: error: <identifier> expected
        public void static main(String args[])
                   ^
pList.java:87: error: '(' expected
        public void static main(String args[])
                    ^
pList.java:87: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
        public void static main(String args[])
                           ^
3 errors

C:\Users\Dummy\Desktop\Java>
```

Please let me know how I can fix this and where I have made my mistake. Thanks in advance

Comment: static comes before void

Comment: Please show the error **text** here, not in a link or image. You are asking for free advice and thus should put in the effort to make it as easy as possible for others to help you.

Comment: I recommend you start using an IDE, e.g. [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/junosr2)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels cmd is not allowing me to copy paste the text and if I type it I might inadvertently make some mistake. To be on the safe side I posted a screenshot

Comment: @CallMeDummy: cmd *will* let you copy text easily. Simply right click on the cmd window, click *select all*, and then press *enter*, and bingo, all of the text is copied. Next time you run into a similar problem, please do this and then post the error here, as it will simplify our work greatly and will be greatly appreciated by all.

Comment: Don't be so hard on yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the update. 1+ to your question for the effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this:

```
  public void static main(String args[])
```

to

```
  public static void main(String args[])
```

You also need to `import java.util.ArrayList;` in order to use lists. And your list cannot be of type `<int>`, has to be `<Integer>`. An int is a number; an Integer is a pointer that can reference an object that contains a number. Read the difference [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com.ar/2008/08/java-int-versus-integer.html).

Comment: I fixed my code like u showed. But now I am receiving 4 new errors.`C:\Users\Dummy\Desktop\Java>javac pList.java
pList.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        ArrayList<Int> nums = new ArrayList<Int>();
        ^
  symbol:   class ArrayList
  location: class abc
pList.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        ArrayList<Int> nums = new ArrayList<Int>();
                  ^
  symbol:   class Int
  location: class abc`

Comment: the error is too long to fit in one comment so the rest of it is here : `pList.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        ArrayList<Int> nums = new ArrayList<Int>();
                                  ^
  symbol:   class ArrayList
  location: class abc
pList.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        ArrayList<Int> nums = new ArrayList<Int>();
                                            ^
  symbol:   class Int
  location: class abc
4 errors`

Comment: Thank you very much the program runs , I just need to fix the nums.length and nums[i] to  nums.size() and nums.get(i) in my for loop

Answer (score 1):

You want your return type to be *after* the identifier:

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

Additionally, you have generics for `Int`, do you want those to be an `Integer`? You're adding primitives into an ArrayList.

Comment: okay, I made them `ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();` The number of error reduced to 2. `
C:\Users\Dummy\Desktop\Java>javac pList.java
pList.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ^
  symbol:   class ArrayList
  location: class abc
pList.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                                      ^
  symbol:   class ArrayList
  location: class abc
2 errors

C:\Users\Dummy\Desktop\Java>`

Answer (score 0):

You shoul use NetBeans if you are a learner programmer
You must use the return type for the main method too because it has a return type set to void